Mantra to attract someone as my life partner
Is there a Spell / Mantra with instructions that can be used to grant my wish of getting the person I love as my partner and future husband?

You can chant 18th Shloka of Soundarya lahiri

तनुच्छायाभिस्ते तरुणतरणिश्रीसरणिभिः दिवं सर्वामुर्वीमरुणिमनि मग्नां
स्मरति यः ।
भवन्त्यस्य त्रस्यद्वनहरिणशालीननयनाः सहोर्वश्या वश्याः कति कति न
गीर्वाणगणिकाः ॥ १८॥

Translation:

Instructions to chant:

Chant this mantra 1000 times everyday for 45 days. If you can offer
payasam(Kheer) and thamboolam to god.


Here's one of the Sarva-akarshana Mantras of Sri Sankarshana (Balaram or Nityananda who is the brother of Lord Krishna).
Slowly carve the Mantra in big size in the air in front of you by moving your palm or index-finger while gazing at every Akshara or syllable in the mind with full concentration. The sequence to draw the Aksharas is given in the below picture:

It is from the Gaudiya Vaishnava lineage and can be practiced by anyone who has Shraddha i.e., Faith / an open heart, which is the only requirement.
There're no strict rules to be followed due to the Mantra-Devata's extremely liberal nature.

patita-prana-dah prthvi-pavano bhakta-vatsalah premananda-madonmatta
brahmadi-nama-gocarah
To those in the world of birth and death, Nitai bestows the
energy of material and spiritual life. He purifies the earth. He is
affectionate to His devotees and remains intoxicated in spiritual bliss. His sacred Mantra
is meditated upon by Lord Brahma and other celestial beings to fulfill their desires.
sarva-mantra-svarupas ca
Nitai is the personification of all Mantras which exist in
creation.
~ Shri-Nityaananda-Ashtottara-Shata-Naama-Stotra

Note:
Do not use the Mantra to cheat or cause pain to others. It is imbued with the cosmic frequences of existence to align us with prakriti or nature, as shown above.
If beneficial for one's soul, the Mantra can fulfill any desire including getting a desired life partner.
